# Admin Edit single product or manage categories error

Tags: php, magento, syntax-error, admin

I was make last things to magento ecommerce committed by a customer of mine. I was looking in admin if all is good and I found when i click in a signle product or click in manage categories, magento crash and give me the famous "

There has been an error processing your request.

Below the full error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:100:"Sorgente modello "instagramconnect/source_instagram" non trovata per l\'attributo "instagram_source"";i:1;s:3200:"#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(390): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Sorgente modell...')
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(203): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Attributes.php(70): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(922): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#12 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#13 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#14 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(Array, true, true)
#15 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(250): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout(Array)
#16 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->editAction()
#17 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#18 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php(82): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}";s:3:"url";s:97:"/index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/2809/key/f476404be4de46eba4e407d47f104f0c/css/styles.css";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Tried to reindex all, to delete cache, but nothing changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to disable Instagram Extension and check it. I think this module is through an exception.

Comment: Tried to disable all modules in local.xml, error still persist

Comment: disable from etc/ and check it.

Comment: can you please share instagram module sql file?i think this module made changes in core files.

Comment: The problem is that i removed this module, and i haven't a backup copy ready to install with me. This is an existing project and i managed to remove some modules.
I already did it from etc/ - if i go in module folder, there is no presence of instagram module also.

Comment: I think Instagram module creates some product attributes so when you save or edit product then it creates problem. so i need to admin username and password to check this. actually difficult to tracking down the issue.

Comment: I'm in local, not have at the moment access from WAN. This error show up with manage categories also.

Comment: let me know please module company name.

Comment: goto Catalog->Manage Attributes
and delete this two attributes.
instagram_source and
instagram_source_user hope this helps.

Comment: I manage the situation entering in attributes details and changing targeted products to " bundle" only, as there are not product bundle it's worked for solve the single product display in admin side. The problem with "manage categories " persist, found in error code that the attribut involved is "instagram_category_source" , where there is not in manage attribute list like others

Comment: Found on internet one .PDF of iKantam where is also an SQL script to run after module unistall for clean DB from not necessary attributes.

Now i'm still facing error when i click on manage categories, but it's different 

 `a:5:{i:0;s:99:"Sorgente modello "custommenu/config_source_category_label" non trovata per l\'attributo "cat_label"";i:1;s:4073:"#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(390): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Sorgente modell...')`

Comment: Now i have blank page in front end showing this :

`Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Themeframework_Helper_Settings' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/Mage.php on line 547`